# What was the highest number of floppy disks ever used for a product?

Tags: history, floppy

Something I got to thinking of while sorting out a pile of driver floppies for windpws XP & 2003...

Of all the software products ever released, what came on the highest number of floppy disks?  Windows 95 used 13, but I doubt that was the upper limit as things moved towards dual-release on floppy and CD before becoming CD only.

Comment: Should take this over to http://superuser.com

Comment: I thought '95 was > 13... I remember sitting there for the best part of a day swapping them out

Comment: funny, i just threw out an old Win95 retail box full of the original floppies...

Comment: the update version was 25 disks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know if it was publicly released, but I remember that when I was with one customer who had a very old (but powerful) machine and were licence customers of Microsoft, they requested XP on disk and it was delivered on around 250+ floppys

Comment: Whatt? Seriously? XP on floppies? Well, that's somehow cool...

Comment: I am sure I still have it somewhere, (I never throw computer related stuff away!)... I will try to go to the attic and find it a bit later

Comment: that must have sucked when you found disk 249 was bad.

Comment: I wanna see pics!

Comment: Imagine spending payroll on someone installing an OS from 250 floppies rather than just buying a CD-ROM drive.

Answer (score 9):

MS Office 97 Professional came on <del>45 floppies</del> [55 floppies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc767941.aspx) (97 Standard came on 45).

Comment: I have a copy of MS Office 4.3 from back before cd's existed, and that was 43 floppies.

Answer (score 5):

OS/2 Warp v3 was 25 (39 if you include the bonus pack) - and i know because i just dusted it off and counted :) now can i find a working floppy drive?

Comment: Thanks for doing that so I didn't have to go count :D

Comment: I have a totally working USB floppy drive in my office desk drawer, and you'd be amazed by no *litte* use it sees these days! :) But still, every so often, I need to install Win XP x64 for instance, and suddenly I have to pop a driver in there.. :)

Comment: ..and by "no *litte* use" I actually mean "how *little* use"... PEBKAC problem..:)

Answer (score 2):

I still have the disks for [Microsoft C++ 7.0](http://www.emsps.com/oldtools/mscppv.htm) here in my drawer. There are 16 of them.

Answer (score 2):

Slackware Linux came on 33 disks.

Answer (score 1):

I recall hearing that MS SQL Server was quite a few disks (I want to say around 40), but can't find the exact number anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

MS Office Pro, 40+ disks, as far as I can remember...

Answer (score 1):

How about for games?  [Monkey Island 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_Island_2:_LeChuck%27s_Revenge) came on 11 disks for the Amiga - and hard drives weren't that common!

Comment: That was double density floppies though, not HD ones. Not sure if they would only count half :] But yes, good times swapping disks! I managed to finish the thing on a floppy only machine.

Answer (score 0):

I remember Lotus SmartSuite used 23...

Answer (score 0):

i remember that Borland C++ was on 15 disks